# Using a single command to run different tests in different modes

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have two command lines:

```
testcafe firefox ./tests/desktop/*.js
testcafe 'chrome:emulation:device=iphone X' ./tests/mobile/*.js
```

How can I combine these two command lines into one command line?

For example:

```
testcafe 'chrome:emulation:device=iphone X' ./tests/mobile/*.js, firefox ./tests/desktop/*.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As TestCafe demonstrates running tests in multiple browsers with a single command [here](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402639/reference/command-line-interface#local-browsers) as well as [here](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402830/guides/basic-guides/run-tests#run-tests-concurrently), you could try the following:

```js
testcafe firefox,'chrome:emulation:device=iphone X' ./tests/desktop/*.js
```

if you want to run different tests for different browsers, you could spin up different testcafe instances/test sessions for each set of tests:

```js
testcafe firefox ./tests/desktop/*.js & 
testcafe 'chrome:emulation:device=iphone X' ./tests/mobile/*.js
```

This second part of the answer, containing the `&` operator was inspired by the documentation regarding [parallel test execution with TestCafè provided by BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/getting-started/nodejs/testcafe/run-tests-in-parallel).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But I need to run 2 different paths:
'./tests/desktop/*.js' runs in firefox, './tests/mobile/*.js' runs in 'chrome:emulation:device=iphone X'. Is it possible to write one command line for this?

Comment: You're right, I disregarded that part in the previous version of my answer. Check out the updated version.

Comment: Glad to hear it helps!